# Python xlsxwriter set_indent is not able to do indentation

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am using a library called xlsxwriter in python for creating a Excel file. I am using 'set_indent' to use indentation before my text in a cell, but i am not sure why it's not working.

**Code:-**

```
 workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Example.xlsx")
 worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("My_Sheet")
 cell_indent_format = workbook.add_format().set_indent(2)
 worksheet.write('B20', "HELLO", cell_indent_format)
```

[image: Added screenshot]

Comment: I have the same problem. No way to get it work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work. Just split out the method calls:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Example.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("My_Sheet")
cell_indent_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_indent_format.set_indent(2)

worksheet.write('B20', "HELLO", cell_indent_format)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had the same issue, but actually my issue was the inability to use this in **conditional** formatting. In the normal cell formatting it worked though.

Comment: Yes, Excel doesn't support the full range of cell formatting in Conditional Formatting. Indentation is one of the formatting options that isn't supported. You can still add it to a conditionally formatted cell, just not as part of the conditional format.